# Scala: Boilerplate-free pimping

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, implicit-conversion, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I make extensive use of the [Pimp my Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern, and I'd like to remove the boilerplate. For example, say I have some trait PrettyPrint:

```
trait PrettyPrint { def prettyPrint: String }
```

If I want to pimp Int and Double, I need to write code like this:

```
implicit def int2PrettyPrint(self: Int) = 
  new PrettyPrint { def prettyPrint = "Int: " + self }
implicit def double2PrettyPrint(self: Double) = 
  new PrettyPrint { def prettyPrint = "Double: " + self }
```

In the above, I'd classify as boilerplate: 1) The name of the implicit conversion, 2) The "new" keyword, 3) Perhaps the argument name "self", 4) Perhaps the "implicit" keyword. I'd rather write something like this:

```
@pimp[Int, PrettyPrint] { def prettyPrint = "Int: " + self }
@pimp[Double, PrettyPrint] { def prettyPrint = "Double: " + self }
```

On the right hand sides of the above code, the name "self" is assumed to be the conversion argument.

Ideas on how to do this?

Some notes:

1) I'm amenable to using Scala 2.10 if necessary.

2) The new implicit classes in Scala 2.10 *don't suffice* as far as I can tell. This is because there is only one implicit conversion for each implicit class. In other words, code like the following wouldn't compile because PrettyPrint is declared twice:

```
implicit class PrettyPrint(self: Int) = ...
implicit class PrettyPrint(self: Double) = ...
```

Comment: @pr1001, yes. Do you have pointers for how to do this, or good links to read?

Comment: So far macros cannot make globally visible changes (e.g. add public members or classes). We might add this functionality in one of the 2.10.x releases, but no promises.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, so what does that leave me with? An annotation plus a compiler plugin?

Comment: How 'bout a code generator?  Do you really need to do this so much in so many places in the code that it's faster to write a compiler plugin than it is to write a little bit of code that spits out the expanded code you need?

Comment: A code generator would be perfect, so long as I could integrate it seamlessly into my build process (SBT and Eclipse). Any pointers?

Comment: Not from me, since I don't really do the SBT/Eclipse thing.  But given that I was automatically building stuff with code generators in C 20 years ago, I have to imagine it's still possible.

Comment: @emchristiansen Looks like that's the only way to satisfy all your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow-up on our [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nativelibs4java/o577ZXRAheQ/discussion) on NativeLibs4Java's mailing list, where I gave an example of [such a compiler plugin](https://gist.github.com/ochafik/4978627) (which expands `@extend(Int) def foo = blah` into `implicit class foo(self: Int) extends AnyVal { def foo = blah }`).

I've written [a more elaborated plugin](https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy/tree/master/MacroExtensions) that expands these definitions into... macros (giving macro-expandable extensions / "pimps", with no runtime dependency!).

Given:

```
@extend(Any) def quoted(quote: String): String = quote + self + quote
```

It expands to:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
implicit class scalaxy$extensions$quoted$1(self: Any) {
  def quoted(quote: String) = macro scalaxy$extensions$quoted$1.quoted
}
object scalaxy$extensions$quoted$1 {
  def quoted(c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)
            (quote: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._
    val Apply(_, List(selfTree$1)) = c.prefix.tree
    val self = c.Expr[Any](selfTree$1)
    {
      reify(quote.splice + self.splice + quote.splice)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just name your implicit classes differently:

```
implicit class PrettyPrintInt(self: Int) = ...
implicit class PrettyPrintDouble(self: Double) = ...
```

Comment: This has two problems: 1) It only slightly reduces boilerplate, 2) (Major problem) It changes the semantics. If I have some function "def foo(prettyPrint: PrettyPrint) ...", I can no longer pass it an Int or a Double.

Comment: @emchristiansen: Why not? `PrettyPrint` is a trait and the implicit classes can extend `PrettyPrint`.

Comment: @sschaef, you don't end up saving characters if you do that. The whole point of implicit classes is to collapse the trait definition and the implicit definition into one definition. If you used implicit classes but also had to define a PrettyPrint super trait, you'd lose that savings. Plus, you'd have to write "extends PrettyPrint" at each implicit class definition.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution that requires signiicantly more boilerplate up front, in exchange for slightly less clutter for each specific instanciation of `PrettyPrint`:

```
implicit class PrettyPrintable[T]( val self: T ) extends AnyVal { 
  def prettyPrint( implicit impl: PrettyPrint[T]): String = impl.prettyPrint( self ) 
}
trait PrettyPrint[T]{ def prettyPrint( self: T ): String }
object PrettyPrint {
  def apply[T]( impl: T => String ): PrettyPrint[T] = new PrettyPrint[T] {
    def prettyPrint( self: T ) = impl( self )
  }
}

implicit val int2PrettyPrint = PrettyPrint[Int]( "Int: " + _ )
implicit val double2PrettyPrint = PrettyPrint[Double]( "Double: " + _ )
// Or more explicitly:
//implicit val int2PrettyPrint = PrettyPrint{self: Int => "Int: " + self }
//implicit val double2PrettyPrint = PrettyPrint{self: Double => "Double: " + self }
```

Compare:

```
implicit def int2PrettyPrint(self: Int) = new PrettyPrint { def prettyPrint = "Int: " + self }
```

to:

```
implicit val int2PrettyPrint = PrettyPrint[Int]( "Int: " + _ )
```

You still need the `implicit` keyword though, as well as a unique name for the implicit value

Comment: +1 This is pretty good, but it looks to me like the compiler plugin is the way to go.

Comment: BTW, isn't the "extends AnyVal" in your answer unnecessary? I think all reference types extend AnyVal automatically.

Comment: No, they extend AnyRef by default. Extending AnyVal makes it a "value class" (works in scala 2.10 only(. You can remove it, it is only an optimization.

Comment: Note though that I used another feature of scala 2.10: PrettyPrintable is an implicit class. For scala < 2.10, make it a normal class and add an implicit conversion by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Summary after 1 week: It appears I need to write a compiler plugin to get the exact behavior I specified.